# How do I install glibc 2.12 in ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: ubuntu, glibc

I have a 64-bit ubuntu 12.04 installation， with a glibc version 2.15, but the machine I need to run on has a glibc version 2.12, when I ran the program compiled on my own machine on the target machine, it gave me an error: version 'GLIBC_2.14' not found.

It is impossible to upgrade the target machine's glibc, so I think maybe I can install another  glibc in my machine.

Until now, I have tried to downloaded the source of glibc2.12 to make and make install, but I got some syntax error in the source, maybe it's because that the version of my gcc is higher than glibc2.21 needs.

And now I am trying to install a older distribution by chroot way, but I have not made it.

Do you have some proposals?

Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Multiple glibc libraries on a single host](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/847179/multiple-glibc-libraries-on-a-single-host)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> maybe I can install another glibc in my machine.

You can; details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/851229/50617).

EDIT:

> that post ... doesn't mention how to install the new glibc

The "regular" way:

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/glibc-2.12 && make && sudo make install
```

Comment: Yes, I have read that post before, but it doesn't mention how to install the new glibc, just the way to use the new glibc, but what I need is to how to install the new glibc in my machine.

Comment: I have tried that, but unfortunatelly it didn't work. But I found that there was compile environment on the target machine, so I transferred my source code to it and compiled successfully. :)